# How to Call SMSReceiver class from a toggle button push

Tags: android, android-intent, sms, broadcastreceiver

I am looking to make an app that intercepts sms messages given certain parameters. As of now I have a toggle button registered as well as the SMSReceiver class working however i am unable to figure out a way to only have the SMSReceiver working when the toggle is enabled and the SMSReceiver stop working when the toggle is disabled.

Main.Java

public class Main extends Activity {

```
Intent in = new Intent();
IntentFilter intentFilter;
String drivingMessage;
String originAddress;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

   intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
   intentFilter.addAction("SMS_RECEIVED_ACTION");

}

BroadcastReceiver intentReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver(){
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent){
        originAddress = intent.getExtras().getString("sms");
        Toast.makeText(context, originAddress, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
};

@Override
protected void onResume(){
    registerReceiver(intentReceiver, intentFilter);
    super.onResume();
}

@Override
protected void onPause(){
    unregisterReceiver(intentReceiver);
    super.onPause();
}


public void serviceEnabled(View view){
    ToggleButton tB = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.serviceToggle);


    boolean on = tB.isChecked();

    if(on){
        Toast.makeText(this, " toggle is on ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();




    } else{
        Toast.makeText(this, " toggle is off " , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }




}
```

}

SMSReceiver.Java

```
public class SMSReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent){

    Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
    SmsMessage[] msgs = null;
    String str = "SMS From";
    if(bundle != null){
        Object [] pdus = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
        msgs = new SmsMessage[pdus.length];
        for(int i=0; i<msgs.length; i++){
            msgs[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[])pdus[i]);

            if (i == 0){
                str += msgs[i].getOriginatingAddress();

            }

        }

        Intent broadcastIntent = new Intent();
        broadcastIntent.setAction("SMS_RECEIVED_ACTION");
        broadcastIntent.putExtra("sms", str);
        context.sendBroadcast(broadcastIntent);


        this.abortBroadcast();
    }

}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated as this is a project for a class. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your toggle button is kind of an user preference/setting, you can save the status as a boolean flag in SharedPreferences.
 Then in your SMSReceiver, before processing the incoming message you can check the status flag from SharedPreferences and proceed accordingly.

```
public void serviceEnabled(View view){

ToggleButton tB = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.serviceToggle);


boolean on = tB.isChecked();
SharedPreferences preferences=PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
Editor editor=preferences.edit();
editor.putBoolean("is_sms_on", on);
editor.commit();

if(on){
    Toast.makeText(this, " toggle is on ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();




} else{
    Toast.makeText(this, " toggle is off " , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}




}
```

SMSReceiver.Java

```
public class SMSReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent){

SharedPreferences preferences=PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context)
boolean isServiceOn=preferences.getBoolean("is_sms_on",true);
if(isServiceOn){
Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
SmsMessage[] msgs = null;
String str = "SMS From";
if(bundle != null){
    Object [] pdus = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
    msgs = new SmsMessage[pdus.length];
    for(int i=0; i<msgs.length; i++){
        msgs[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[])pdus[i]);

        if (i == 0){
            str += msgs[i].getOriginatingAddress();

        }

    }

    Intent broadcastIntent = new Intent();
    broadcastIntent.setAction("SMS_RECEIVED_ACTION");
    broadcastIntent.putExtra("sms", str);
    context.sendBroadcast(broadcastIntent);


    this.abortBroadcast();
}
}

}
```

Comment: This works I left the unregister line in my else statement. Thank you, you literally saved me and my project haha!

Answer (score 0):

Try unregistering the receiver when the toggle button is unchecked.

```
public void serviceEnabled(View view){
    ToggleButton tB = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.serviceToggle);


    boolean on = tB.isChecked();

    if(on){
        //your code

    } else{
       unregisterReceiver(intentReceiver);
    }




}
```

Comment: I tried inserting the BroadcastReceiver class along with the onReceive method into the Toggle is ON section and unregistered it in the Off section however nothing ia happening at all. Not sure why that is either.

Answer (score 0):

Try disabling the receiver directly from the manifest when toggle button is unchecked that way the receiver is not in picture at all.Use this in the else part of your service enabled function

```
PackageManager pm=getPackageManager();
ComponentName componentName=new ComponentName(getApplicationContext(),yourreceiver.class);//where yourreceiver is the name of your receiver class
      pm.setComponentEnabledSetting(componentName,PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED,PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
```